# Pull records loaded at a particular time everyday from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

Hi
I am using Oracle Database.
I want to pull the records which are loaded between 1:55 PM to 2:10 PM everyday, regardless of the date.
What SQL query should I use, I have a date_upd column which stores the Updated date time information for each record.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd do it:

```
SELECT *
  FROM <your_table>
 WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_upd,'HH24MI')) BETWEEN 1355 AND 1410;
```